# Flutter: How to change previous navigation route without actually navigating?

Tags: flutter

My users will navigate to screen 1, then screen 2 then screen 3.

When they click the back button on screen 3, depending upon a variable in that screen, I want the back button to either take them back to screen 2 or screen 1.

Note: the back button must be trigger by the user, I don't to pragmatically navigate back.

I thought I could use WillPopScope but that can only return a bool.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () {
    return true
  },
  child: Scaffold(
  ...
  ),
 );
}
,
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
return WillPopScope(
  onWillPop: () async => true,
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        onPressed: () {
          _user.isRegistered
          ? Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) => route.isFirst) // Takes the user to the first page
          : Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()));
        },
      ),
```